# Build linq query dynamically

Tags: linq

I have linq statement like below:

```
var biosample= (from a in db.Biosample
                 select a);

if (catalognbr != -1)
{ 
    biosample.Where (a => a.Catalog_nbr ==catalognbr);
}
```

if user selected catalognbr then the query concatenate the where condition, otherwise it skips the where. Right now it does not work the way I want. How to make it work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can incorporate your check for catalognbr in the query

```
var biosample= (from a in db.Biosample
             select a)
           .Where (a => catalognbr == -1 || a.Catalog_nbr ==catalognbr);
```

You could also make your initial attempt work by assigning the result back to biosample

```
var biosample= (from a in db.Biosample
                 select a);
if (catalognbr != -1)
{ 
    biosample = biosample.Where (a => a.Catalog_nbr ==catalognbr);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but when the catalognbr ==-1, the query should return all. And how to do multiple where clause, such as add campus==campusstr, etc.

Answer (score 0):

write like this in your code;

```
biosample = biosample.Where (a => a.Catalog_nbr ==catalognbr);
```